# How to post dictionary to Google sheets in single call

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am trying to post data to google sheets. I am reading a local excel sheet with the python results and trying to port that to google sheets.

I am using something like: (Where I iterate through each key value pair in dictionary and paste it). Is there any easier way to do this, (to avoid getting rate limited?).

```
for each_result in range(0,len(data_local_dic)):
    for key in data_local_dic[each_result].keys():
        data = data_local_dic[each_result][key]
        print(type(data))
        sheet.update_cell(row,column,data)
        column = column+1
    row = row+1
    column=1
    if(row%2==0):
        print("Sleeping to give API some breathing time.")
        time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples of batchUpdate and append

```
    def __init__(self, spreadsheetId: str = "undefined", workbookName = "") -> None:
        self.spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId
        self.__connectToService()
        if workbookName != "":
            self.spreadsheetId = self.findSpreadsheet(workbookName)
            # if workbook was not found,  create it
            if self.spreadsheetId == "":
                s = self.service.spreadsheets().create(body={"properties":{"title":workbookName}}).execute()
                self.spreadsheetId = s.get("spreadsheetId")

    ###########
    # PRIVATE methods
    ###########
    def __connectToService(self):
        """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.

        Creates a Sheets API service object and prints the names and majors of
        students in a sample spreadsheet:
        https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
        """
        credentials = self.__get_credentials()
        self.service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
        # v3 is not working !!!!
        self.driveservice = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

    def findSpreadsheet(self, title:str) -> str:
        id = []
        page_token = None
        while True:
            response = self.driveservice.files().list(q="title='{title}' and trashed=false and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'".format(title=title),
                                                       spaces='drive',
                                                       fields='nextPageToken, items(id, title, mimeType)',
                                                       pageToken=page_token).execute() # type: ignore
            #print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
            for file in response.get('items', []):
                # Process change
                #print(file)
                id.append(file["id"])
            page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
            if page_token is None:
                break

        if id==[]: # not found
            id.append("")
        elif len(id) > 1:
            raise Exception("Too many spreadsheets {}".format(id))

        return id[0]


    def uploadArray(self, values:list, sheetname:str, cell:str="!A1") -> int:
        data = [{'range': sheetname + cell, 'values': values}]
        body = {'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED', 'data': data}
        result = self.service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(
            spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheetId, body=body).execute()

        # print(result);
        return result['totalUpdatedCells']

    # https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values
    def appendArray(self, values:list, sheetname:str) ->int:
        body = {'values': values}
        result = self.service.spreadsheets().values().append(
            spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheetId, range=sheetname+"!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body=body).execute()

        # print(result);
        return result.get("updatedCells")
```

Comment: this looks like some of the methods of a class. But how does it work and how can on implement the above ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sheetfu library](https://github.com/socialpoint-labs/sheetfu) to do that in just one go.

All you need is to have your excel data in the form of 2D matrix (or list of list, where each sublist is a row from your excel sheet).

Once you have your 2D matric, this is all it takes:

```
from sheetfu import SpreadsheetApp

excel_data = [
# put your excel rows in there
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
]

sa = SpreadsheetApp('path/to/secret.json')
spreadsheet = sa.open_by_id('<insert spreadsheet id here>')
sheet = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
data_range = sheet.get_range(
    row=1, 
    column=1, 
    number_of_rows=len(excel_data), 
    number_of_columns=len(excel_data[0])
)
data_range.set_values(excel_data)
```

This should send data to your sheet in just one request.